# hypsometric colors alà IMHOF, SYDOW or PEUCKNER

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, color, colortable

I need a hypsometric color-map to add it to my multishade-model. (High Mountain between 800 and 4000m) There are a lot of different types explained in IMHOFS "Cartographic Relief Presentation". I want to do it traditionally... :-)

So, where can I find "prebuild" colormaps alà PEUCKNER, IMHOF or SYDOW? (I don't like the "Terrain" or "SRTM" ones from Grass)

Comment: If you point us to some sources (i.e. values) of the indicated color tables, we'll be happy to add them in GRASS. Note that you can easily define your own in r.colors (http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/r.colors.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using gdaldem color-relief there is a colour ramp somewhere near the bottom of this page:

http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aide:Cartographie

It's not bad for some purposes, but not wonderful. Better perhaps with the colours faded a little? As you know, EI suggests elevation intervals in the sequence 0,25,50,100,250,500,1000...x, it might be possible to sort out some suitable colours from the above ramp. Nick.

Comment: Thats a nice one, thank you. It carries the idea of Imhof and suits good for my area! But i'm looking for more to compare... any ideas?